# dynamic URLs in java web application (like in rails)

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, servlets, routes

I'm a Ruby on Rails developer programming a web application in Java. I am trying to achieve something similar to what is achieved in Rails. In Rails it is possible to call a link using `localhost:8000\Users\1` when Users is a Model and 1 is the id of a specific user. I would like to get the same kind of thing in Java.

I am working in an MVC type design where my JSP pages are the view and my Servlets are the controllers. I created a servlet called `Users` which renders the `users.jsp` page now i can get to that page using the URL `localhost:8000\projectName\Users`, i would like to route `localhost:8000\projectName\Users\1` to the page `user.jsp` while the appropriate Servlet will handle sending into the page the correct user (with id=1).

Any idea how I can achieve this?

I'm doing this in a University project and am not allowed to use any frameworks. I also would rather something i could code rather than install.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *now i can get to that page using the URL localhost:8000\projectName\Users, i would like to route localhost:8000\projectName\Users\1 to the page user.jsp while the appropriate Servlet will handle sending into the page the correct user (with id=1).*

Simple. Map the servlet on an URL pattern of `/Users/*` instead of `/Users`. You can then grab the path info (the part *after* `/Users` in the URL, which is thus `/1` in your example) as follows:

```
String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();
// ...
```

You can just forward to `users.jsp` the usual way.

```
Long id = Long.valueOf(pathInfo.substring(1));
User user = userService.find(id);
request.setAttribute("user", user);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/users.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Ok... almost there. I get null from `request.getPathInfo()` is this a mistake or am i using it wrong.

Comment: That will happen if there is no pathinfo. You seem not to have changed the mapping from `/Users` to `/Users/*` or to have a dangling/second mapping on `/Users`. Fix it accordingly. As stated in my answer, you should use `/Users/*` **instead of** `/Users` (and thus not have both as incorrectly suggested in the answer of someone else here). Another possible cause is that you used a filter instead of a servlet, but that's a too obvious mistake.

Answer (score 3):

I would try this via a servlet and servlet mappings like that in `web.xml`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>UserServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.UserServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UserServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Users</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UserServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Users/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Than in your `UserServlet` try to get the full URL and parse it to your needs. Example:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {

   String url = reg.getRequestURL();

   //... get last part after slash and parse it to your id

}
```

See http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html for further documentation on the request and how its parameters can be retrieved

Answer (score 1):

[UrlRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)  is like mod_rewrite but for Tomcat. You can use it to make your URLs SEO-friendly. You can also use Apache+mod_rewrite+Tomcat.

Comment: You just have to copy the files into WEB-INF, that is hardly installing. ;) Good luck with that requirement.

Comment: [Manual](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/3.2/index.html) on how to configure it.