# Can I have custom servlet URL in java?

Tags: java, servlets

I want that when user hits following URL:

```
http://host:8080/AppName/ServletName/Param1/Param2
```

It should go to a servlet named `ServletName` and `Param1` and `Param2` become request parameters. I have seen these kind of urls in ruby projects. Is it possible in Java?

Comment: BalusC has posted an awnser to this somewhere, let me look.

Comment: Here is [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678029/dynamic-urls-in-java-web-application-like-in-rails/6678490#6678490)

Comment: @cularis: Yes it is. +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like that with a servlet. You need to set the servlet mapping in web.xml like this:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ServletName/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

to get all requests and in the servlet you need to parse the result of [`HttpServletRequest.getPathInfo()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Spring MVC you can map a [`@Controller`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.html) and access the params as [`@PathVariable`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html) in a [`@RequestMapping`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html).

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

  @RequestMapping("/{param1}/{param2})
  public Response get(@PathVariable("param1") String param1, @PathVariable("param2") String param2) {
    //method body
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[HttpServletRequest.getContextpath()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29) seems interesting, even though i have never used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, it's called [REST](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer), and you can get an intro here: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html

You can also map servlets to wildcarded paths, so you could just map your servlet to `/ServletName/*` and get the `/Param1/Param2` part from [`request.getPathInfo()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this with [URL rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). There is also a servlet container equivalent available that works with a ServletFilter called [UrlRewriteFilter](http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/).

I personally use [Tapestry5](http://tapestry.apache.org/) which natively encodes parameters this way.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this,even haven't seen but try this

first map the url in the web.xml like this

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ServletName</servlet-class>
</servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ServletName/Param1/Param2</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and then get the url to a string using 
  `String url=request.getRequestURI()`;

then you can split and get param1 and param2.