# Friendly URLs with Tomcat

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

I want to be able to have URLs going to servlets like http://host/Servlet/1 rather than http://host/Servlet?ID=1

Any suggestions for how this can be accomplished? Preferably with multiple levels too, so I could do something like http://host/Servlet/1/Files

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I have custom servlet URL in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995953/can-i-have-custom-servlet-url-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HttpServletRequest exposes a method, [getPathInfo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29), which gives you information about the request URL after the servlet path itself. You could map your servlet to /Servlet/* and then get the ID with getPathInfo().

Comment: That would be perfect. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a "must do using Tomcat alone" requirement, I suggest you set up an Apache layer in front of Tomcat where you can have such and other complex URL Rewrites set up.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this could be to have your controller-servlet in front to dispatch to correct servlet in behind depending on the request URI from getRequestURI on the HttpServletRequest.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Filter. Dispatch incoming URL by some rules and redirect to dispatched URL.